# How to draw hover and mousedown colors in Button.OnPaint

Tags: c#, winforms, button, onpaint

How should I draw a Button background in OnPaint, including the hover and mouse down colors?

The code below only draws the background color. It does not draw the mouseover color when the mouse enters, and it does not draw the mousedownback color when you click.

Is there an alternative to base.OnPaintBackground I should be calling instead?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Does not draw hover and mousedown colors
    base.OnPaintBackground(e);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You need to check an store that state in `OnMouseDown()` and `OnKeyDown()`. Reset in the opposite methods. Same for `OnMouseHover()` -- Why do you have `base.OnPaintBackground(e);` in the `OnPaint()` body? -- SolidBrush is Disposable, you cannot have `new SolidBrush()` there, you need to initialize the Brush with a `using` statement.

Comment: @Jimi To answer your question: base.OnPaintBackground(e); is in OnPaint() body because OnPaintBackground is never called for Buttons unless the background is transparent. (There's a post on this subject) Thanks for the tip on the "using" statement!

Comment: Yes, sure. Add this to the Button's Constructor: `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |  ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);` and override `OnPaintBackground()` After that, add `ControlStyles.Opaque`. *Something* changes. Now you can do your job (even though it's not clear what that is: do you want to change the Font? The position where the Text is drawn? Other? BTW, to draw the Text correctly, you need to provide a Rectangle, not a point, as the bounds reference).

Comment: I'm finding success in ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(...) when the mouse is over the control, and may post that as a possible answer. But I'm waiting to see if there's a better one first.

Comment: If you set `ControlStyles.Opaque`, there's no background, so you can paint whatever you want: solid color, translucent, transparent, partially transparent with an anti.aliased round profile... What you're trying to do is not clear. Just paint the background with a custom color? Or repaint the Button with the default Theme colors (why not just paint the Text, then)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just want the default button background colors. I can handle everything else. OnPaintBackground doesn't do the job. ButtonRenderer seems to!

Comment: If you want the default rendering, why don't you just paint what you need to paint in `OnPaint()` and leave the Button class do its stuff for the rest? -- With the `ControlStyles` I described, you can replace everything (but keep the base functionality). If you don't want to, well, just don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with. I'm not happy with ButtonRenderer.DrawButton() because I believed base.OnPaintBackground() should have handled mouse hover and click drawing. Nevertheless, this works nicely.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Background painting
    base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    bool MouseInControl = e.ClipRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    if (MouseInControl)
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Normal);

    // Now paint other stuff on top
}
```